# ConcurrentHashMap atomic get, increment and replace

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, atomic

Is there an easy way to get, increment and replace an integer from a `ConcurrentHashMap`?

```
ConcurrentHashMap<MyResource, AtomicInteger> map;
```

Let's say that every value has already been initialized like this:

```
map.get(i) = new AtomicInteger(0);
```

and that we do not add any new keys.

**How can I make a get, increment and replace atomic (and thread safe)?**

Something like this, should not work:

```
map.get(myResourceKey).incrementAndGet();
```

Because 2 threads could get the same integer before incrementing it right?

The map is keeping track of how many threads are using a certain resource.
And I want something to happen only when a resource is not used (counter = 0).

Comment: In that scenario both threads would get the same `AtomicInteger`, both would call `incrementAndGet` and the `AtomicInteger` would get incremented twice. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @Kami Sounds like an X/Y problem, what is the original problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: @assylias : but what if another thread checks if the value is 0 in between? t1 gets 0, t2 gets 0, t3 gets 0 (but it is soon going to be 2!). t3 being the thread that just checks if it is 0 and does not increment anything.

Comment: @Kami What is it that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Kami Well yes, the idea of concurrency is that things change in parallel. If that is a problem then you probably need to rethink your design -> answer bizicop's question.

Comment: @biziclop: I want different threads that are about to use a shared resource to increment a counter (when they are finished with it, they decrement the counter). I have also a thread that can do something on a resource only if no other thread is using it (so he must check if the counter is 0).

Comment: @Kami I don't think you can easily do that with an AtomicInteger. A [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) may be more appropriate or a [ReadWriteLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) - it depends on the details of your use case.

Comment: This sounds like a job for `ReadWriteLock` indeed. The threads that use the shared resource are the readers and the exclusivity-demanding thread is the writer. The trouble with your `AtomicInteger` solution is that it only gets half of the job done, as you rightly pointed out, even if you read 0, it may not be 0 in the next moment. A semantically correct locking scheme must guarantee that while you hold a write lock, no-one can obtain a read lock.

Comment: If I can acquire the readLock as many times as I like, but I can acquire the writeLock only if all the readLocks have been released it is perfect. I am googling, but maybe you know the answer.

Comment: @Kami Yes, that is exactly how `ReadWriteLock` works. In addition, while you have the write lock, everyone asking for a read lock must wait, guaranteeing complete exclusivity for the write thread.

Comment: Looking at all the questions you have issued in one day, I’d say you have a huge [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) which you combine with some kind of chaos programming, hopping from one solution attempt to another without ever thinking it out. That is not a promising way of programming, but regarding solving multi-threading problems it’s even worse.

Comment: @Holger : By rereading these comments and your link about the XY problem (which I learned about today by the way), I realized why I made this impression on you. Then again, I do not think that X is always definable 'in a pure way'.

Comment: @Kami: not having an exact definition of `X`, read the actual problem to solve, may be the root of all problems…

Answer (score 4):

You can use compute to perform atomic operations like the one you're asking for. The compute method will return the incremented value or 1 if it's the first call.

```
ConcurrentMap<MyResource, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

map.compute(resourceKey, (k, v) -> v == null ? 1 : v + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The AtomicInteger will work fine with multiple threads, that's its purpose. So if the map doesn't change, you're fine.

Problems will occur if several threads try to modify the map at the same time, for example two threads adding each their own AtomicInteger. In this case, synchronize the map itself.

Comment: Don't synchronize the map, use `putIfAbsent` or one of the other similar methods...